# Battery weight in quadcopter

Tags: quadcopter, uav

We all know that the fly time of a quadcopter is proportional to its weight (and the propellers size, etc), and a high capacity battery is heavy, but also a high capacity battery would make the fly time larger.

I need a chart or comparison between battery capacity, battery weight, fly time and propellers size for a quadcopter. Or comparison between some of them. I couldn't find that, so any link or help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Every quadcopter design is relatively unique and there's not one answer for any given system. Many factors can change these numbers, for example the type of blade, the material the angle of attack, the efficiency of the speed controllers, the shape of the body and payload, payload battery consumption, etc. There's other factors of things like your flight profile and the environment too which will effect performance.

But a few helpful calculators that I found quickly are:

https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/drone-flight-time This one in particular requires an "Watts to lift 1kg" as a way to capture the overall efficiency of the drone flight system.

Here's another generic one: https://design215.com/dcal/toolbox/flight-time-amps